# Will the next deorbiting reactor be on a "safe disposal" trajectory, or re-enter as an uncontrolled derelict?

Tags: reentry, debris, safety, nuclear, deorbit

> Kosmos 954 was a reconnaissance satellite launched by the Soviet Union
> in 1977, powered by a nuclear reactor containing 50Kg of highly
> enriched uranium-235
>
> Soviet officials … lost control over the vehicle, and the system which
> was intended to propel the spent reactor core into a safe disposal
> orbit … failed.
>
> When the satellite reentered the Earth's atmosphere the following
> year, it scattered radioactive debris over northern Canada. The
> Canadian government billed the Soviet Union for over $6 million under
> the terms of the Outer Space Treaty (which obligates states for
> damages caused by their space objects). The USSR eventually paid 3
> million Canadian dollars in compensation.[4]
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_954

There are currently 32 nuclear reactors in LEO: one SNAP-10A, two Topaz and 29Bouk.
https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=2005ESASP.587..551J&db_key=AST&page_ind=1&plate_select=NO&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_GIF&classic=YES

When the next LEO reactor de-orbits,  will it have the capacity to enter a planned  “safe disposal trajectory”, or will it be an uncontrolled derelict?

Comment: different but related: [How many nuclear fission reactors have been launched into space? How many are still there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27908/12102) and to a lesser extent [Most recent launch of a nuclear reactor, and current barriers to launching the next one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34139/12102)